# ffmpeg do stream copy together with draw text

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I need to record an RTSP stream,  before storing it I need draw some text on the video.

And the below command works fine for recording stream only(no text write).

```
openRTSP -D 10 -v -t -c -b 800000 rtsp://video_link.mov | ./ffmpeg -r 15 -i - -codec copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 "./video/live.m3u8"
```

But I also need to draw some text on the video before recording. So I re-write the above command like

```
openRTSP -D 10 -v -t -c -b 800000 rtsp://video_link.mov | ./ffmpeg -r 15 -i - -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf: text='Some Text': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -codec copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 "./video/live.m3u8"
```

But giving the error like,

```
input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 704x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Filtergraph 'drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf: text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2' was defined for video output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.
```

I understand that both recording and drawing cannot perform together. 
Any method exist similar, to  solve  the above problem?.

Comment: Filtering requires re-encoding, so you can't stream copy and filter the same stream.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so is there any method exist to receive stream->draw some text->write to video file. Or do I need to reopen the recorded  file and then draw text as explained here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17623676/text-on-video-ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Filtering requires re-encoding](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Filtering), so you can't [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) and filter the same stream.

Remove `-codec copy` or avoid filtering. You can still stream copy the audio with `-c:a copy` since it is not being filtered: